# Argument ($username) must be of type string, null given

Tags: php, xero-api

I was trying Xero third party in my application as our back-end is PHP where all our xero api has been written, and we have deployed the PHp code in ubuntu 20

php version is 8.2

Composer version 2.5.5

All other API are working apart from while exporting data from my application to xero its showing this error
(in response i m getting 500 and this error)

> Illuminate\Http\Client\PendingRequest::withBasicAuth(): Argument #1 ($username) must be of type string, null given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Client/Factory.php on line 385",

```
    "exception": "TypeError",

    "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Client/PendingRequest.php",

    "line": 392,

    "trace": [

        {

            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Client/Factory.php",

            "line": 385,

            "function": "withBasicAuth",

            "class": "Illuminate\\Http\\Client\\PendingRequest",

            "type": "->"

        },

        {

            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php",

            "line": 338,

            "function": "__call",

            "class": "Illuminate\\Http\\Client\\Factory",

            "type": "->"

        },

        {

            "file": "/var/www/html/app/Http/Controllers/Api/XeroEndpointController.php",

            "line": 373,

            "function": "__callStatic",

            "class": "Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade",

            "type": "::"

        },

    ]

}
```

I tried different scenarios like:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

and all other commands again same error.